# Redux toolkit, create api with custom tags, don't cleanup internal references

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am testing out the Redux Toolkit query library, using auto generated api code for the petshop in my tests. I have created an enhanched and overwritten tags for some of the endpoints, to be able to invalidate individual data points (see code below). However, when looking in the state tree of redux, it looks like that these id reference are not removed when no longer used. Am I missing something in the configuration, or will these internal references just keep grow during my application lifetime?

```
export const enhancedApi  = api.enhanceEndpoints({
    addTagTypes: ['Pets'],
    endpoints: {
        getPetById: {
            providesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{type: 'Pets', id: arg.petId}],
        },
        updatePet: {
            invalidatesTags: (result, error, arg) => [{type: 'Pets', id: arg.pet.id}]
        }
    },
});
```

A capture of my redux state below shows the `dangling` references, sometime they also reference a key that is no longer part of the `queries` object.

[image: Redux state]